# Automatically Run Command Upon Opening Terminal (Linux Mint 16)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, linux-mint

I am using Rails and for some reason unbeknownst to me I have to execute the following line every time I start the terminal in order to use ruby and rails.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

If I type the following before running the above command, it will recommend that I install the packages (ie "type 'sudo apt-get install package' to install")

```
rails -v && ruby -v && irb -v
```

Is there a way to make my terminal execute a command upon opening? Or, better yet, can anybody help explain the reason I have to run this line? I found an article that said I had to do that given my issue but it didn't explain why.

Comment: if you are using `gnome terminal` and `rvm` I would suggest you read https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `bash` shell, then `~/.bash_profile` will be sourced once (and only once) when you log in to the system but **not** each time you open a terminal window.

The `~/.bashrc`, however, will be sourced every time a new shell is opened (i.e. when you open a terminal window).

So they are probably some environment variables settings in `~/.bash_profile` which are required for `ruby` to run. Those settings should be moved to the `~/.bashrc` file instead so they are defined in all shell instances.

Alternatively, `source ~/.bash_profile` from your `~/.bashrc` (this is at your own risk, it may have side-effects).

Comment: Thank you! I'm generally wary of messing with anything that sounds important in Linux (ie files that make my terminal work) but I figured that once I had the two files open I could revert any changes if I screwed it up. I promptly screwed it all up but managed to figure it out after a mite of trial and error.